# SKYPE4COMLib get others user information?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, skype, skype4com

I'm currently making a skype-tool and I was wondering how to get someone else's user information:

[image]

I have no idea how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the `Friends` array/collection of the Skype client, then match the name with the one you've inputted.

The array consist of all your contacts.

```
var SkypeClient = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
foreach (SKYPE4COMLib.User User in SkypeClient.Friends)
{
    if(User.Handle.ToLower() == TextBoxName.Text.ToLower()) //Using ToLower() for case-insensitive checking.
    {
        TextBoxFullName.Text = User.FullName; //Contact's full name.
        TextBoxMood.Text = User.Mood; //Contact's mood text.
        TextBoxCity.Text = User.City; //Contact's city.
        //...and so on.
        break; //Terminate the loop.
    }
}
```

You can find all sorts of properties in the `SKYPE4COMLib.User` class.

Though keep in mind that `User.Handle` is the contact's **username**, not it's displayed name. If you want to match against it's displayed name instead you have to make the if-statement check `User.DisplayName`.

Refer to their previous API documentation for more information about the classes and properties: http://web.archive.org/web/20130620112019/http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference#OBJECTS

Comment: Thanks!! <3 @VisualVincent

Comment: @SynomousArtz : If I solved your problem please mark my answer as the accepted answer by pressing the green tick on it's left.